# Properly exposing C# methods to jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to ask a question.

Recently, I've learned how to make jQuery use C# methods via consuming from an ASP.NET Web service. I am thinking of exposing some database access methods such as retrieving a list of records from the database for rendering using a jQuery library.

I have on top of my head is that I create a separate project in my solution, which is a Web service project to be able to expose the said data access methods (*located on a separate project also in the solution*). The web service will act as interaction between my jQuery and my data access methods.

I am visualizing my idea like this:

[image: What I envision...]

My question is that, is my idea a good thing to do, and if not, how do you properly expose C# data access objects for use with jQuery?

Thanks!

EDIT: The Web UI is an ASP.NET Web Forms, specifically version 2.0. I'm doing this in preparation to my next job.

Comment: JSON is common datatype helpful to share data from Javascript to C# and Javascript to C#. Both language native support for JSON (and JSONP)

Comment: Typically you'll want to Ajax from jQuery across to the web service directly, so you won't want a WebForms or MVC WebUI in between them. IMO the server HTML generation (WebForms or MVC) are side by side with the JSON / REST API services. Look at using WebAPI for the REST services - it will work with WebForms as well (.Net >= 4.0). So TL;DR guess it depends on whether your `Web UI` block is server side, or client side (Angular, Knockout etc)

Comment: I don't think that you can share your "Business Objects" in this way as documented in this diagram. It should go thru the "Web Service" layer.

Comment: why not use JQuery $.ajax() method ?

Comment: @mmhasannn: The Web Service layer will be the ones to interact with jQuery's $.ajax() method.

Comment: @Thangadurai: I might not understood what Business Objects mean to other developers. In my case, my business objects contain the logical layer of my Web UI.

Comment: @Anirugu: Yea, I'll be using JSON/JSONP for the project use in this diagram

Comment: @StuartLC: Haven't check out the REST services, I've just recently learned using ASMX. The Web UI is ASP.NET Web Forms. I'll update my post to include the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct approach.  Typically, the Web Service is a REST API (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) that returns JSON/JSONP.  This allows the client (JQuery) to use AJAX, async calls to the server.

Web API 2 (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) is an easy way to expose an REST API in c#.

Comment: This might help me in the future, and I'll take my time learning Web API 2.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard has already explain 
i will extend it and suggest you to use [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) instead of simple of calling jquery ajax.

> Why AngularJS?
>
> HTML is great for declaring static documents, but it falters when we
>   try to use it for declaring dynamic views in web-applications.
>   AngularJS lets you extend HTML vocabulary for your application. The
>   resulting environment is extraordinarily expressive, readable, and
>   quick to develop.

[Case Studies for example](https://builtwith.angularjs.org/)

Comment: Interesting! I'll do check it out also =)